# How does one refer to a UITextField created in a method?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am adding `UITextFields` to a `UITableView` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.
Once it's all set up, I need to access them, for example I want to make the keyboard disappear when the background is selected like:

```
- (IBAction)touchBackground:(id)sender {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and scroll to them when they are selected like:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
    [settingsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[settingsTable indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

However they only exist as temporary variables in the method, so i don't know how to refer to them. I could declare them all beforehand in the header file, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to, because this way to add more fields alter all I have to do is add to an array of cell titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an instance variable with this propoerty:

```
@property (assign) UITextField *selectredTextField;
```

Then You will assign the selected field to this instance variable

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
    [settingsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[settingsTable indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    self.selectredTextField = textField;
}
```

now in your method you can resign it

```
- (IBAction)touchBackground:(id)sender {
  [self.selectredTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I have a lot to learn about Objective-C, and OOP in general.